# Enable/Disable Ribbon button based on Excel Sheet Change - VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have written a VSTO Excel application and I am trying to change the button behavior based on the sheets selected. The event is actually Raised in `ThisWorkbook.cs` class and the Ribbon buttons are only accessible in Ribbon.cs class.
Is there any way to enable or disable the ribbon button from ThisWorkbook.cs class without creating the instance of ribbon in `ThisWorkbook.cs` class?

```
void ThisWorkbook_SheetActivate(object Sh)
    {
        if (SomeCondition)
        {
            //Enable button
        }
        else
        {
            //Disable button
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the ribbon via     `Ribbon ribon = Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon;`

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was actually thinking the other way to access the Ribbon buttons in ThisWorkbook.cs